# knockout js passing correct parameter to method

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

when using the click bind in knockout, how does knockout know to pass the correct parameter to the method its bound to?

```
<div id="test" data-bind="click: runTest"/>
</div>


self.runTest = function (coolParameter){
doSomethingCool();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When calling your handler, Knockout will supply the current model
>   value as the first parameter. This is particularly useful if you’re
>   rendering some UI for each item in a collection, and you need to know
>   which item’s UI was clicked.

from [the documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html)

There also is some discussion in the docs about how to pass more parameters by adding a wrapping function

```
<button data-bind="click: function(data, event) { 
    myFunction('param1', 'param2', data, event) 
}">
    Click me
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

knockout understands which value to pass from context. it's the current model object. e.g if you're in a foreach knockout passes the current item.